# Explain how Pr(dx,dy) appears in the derivation of the expected prediction error

Tags: decision-theory

I am working through the book "Elements of Statistical Learning" and I do not understand why $Pr(dx,dy)$ is in equation 2.10

**Background:**

[image]

**This is what I understand so far:**

I am calculating the expectation value of the loss function $L(Y,f(x))$, thus:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
E[L(Y,f(x))] &=& \int L(Y,f(x))\,\, Pr(X,Y)\,dxdy \label{} \\ 
&=&\int[y-f(x)]^2\,Pr(x,y)\,dxdy
\end{eqnarray}
$$

**The question:**
How does $Pr(dx,dy)$ appear in the above equation, e.g. what steps are taken to arrive at the equality below:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int[y-f(x)]^2\,Pr(x,y)\,dxdy = \int[y-f(x)]^2\,Pr(dx,dy)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

**Related posts I've read:**

1. [Expected Error Prediction Derivation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189560/expected-error-prediction-derivation)

   This post says $Pr(x,y)\,dxdy = f_2(x,y)dxdy$

   Is this just standard notation, i.e. that the derivative of a joint distribution function $Pr(x,y)dxdy$ is written as $Pr(dx,dy)$ or $f_2(x,y)dxdy$. In which case is $Pr(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$? So:
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   Pr(x,y)\,dxdy = Pr(dx,dy)
   \end{eqnarray}
   $$

   If this is not just notation, is there a mathematical derivation for
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \int[y-f(x)]^2\,Pr(x,y)\,dxdy = \int[y-f(x)]^2\,Pr(dx,dy)
   \end{eqnarray}
   $$

**Edit**

Changed notation $f(x,y)$ to $f_2(x,y)$ to clarify it is distinct from $f(x)$

Comment: First of all, you use the notation $f$ twice. Once for the statistical "model" $f(X)$ that should be close to $Y$, and once for the resulting joint density of the random variables $X$ and $Y$. That should be avoided. Secondly, assuming $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, it is indeed the case that $Pr(dx,dy)$ in the book really means $Pr(x\leqslant X<x+dx, y\leqslant Y<y+dx) = g_{XY}(x,y) dx dy$, where $g_{XY}(x,y)$ is the joint density of $X$ and $Y$. It is a bit of an unfortunate notation from a strictly calculus point-of-view, but a useful shorthand in probability.

Comment: Yeah I know I used $f$ twice, the related post used $f(x,y)$ which really confused me. I replicated it in case it was intended.

Thanks for the explanation regarding the notation, much appreciated!

Comment: This issue is discussed in several posts on [prediction limits](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prediction+limit%22).  In particular, see the extended discussions of specific prediction limits or intervals at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4174, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134380, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255570.